# Make every Copy and cut paste opearation Paste Special

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am working on C# VSTO(excel). I have created excel workbook project.
I have been trying to implement Paste Special for my workbook.

Manually, we do **paste special** like [**This**](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s2p7.html)

But i need C# code to do the same.

Is there any way so i can apply it for every copy/cut paste operation in my excel workbook?

I don't want to use VBA Macros as it asks everytime user to whether he wants to ENABLE MACROS OR NOT and hence is there another way o accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [PasteSpecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839476.aspx)method over ranges, it provides numerous options to copy formats/ column widths/ fomats with values etc.

Also there is another copy special to copy/paste as picture.

to copy Range:
    Range.CopyPicture(xlPrinter, xlPicture);
    // the range gets copied in clipboard
    // there are options available like xlScreen in case you want to copy as it appears on screen.
    Sheet.Paste()
    // this will paste the shape in the sheet, to paste in some range you could use range.Paste()

Comment: I know this pastespecial method. But it only works if i want to force pastespecial for any specific range. I cannot use it for dynamic copy paste. So if i want every paste operation my worksheet to be past special it fails to do so. Can be done with the macros only.